# T-SQL use linked server query result to populate a local table

Tags: sql

Hi I am trying to get smart ideas how to accomplish this. I have a table T1 with a column named ‘Servers’ containing a whole list of linked server names. And I want to query some tables on each of these linked servers and use the result to populate the other columns, named DB_Nmaes for example, of this table.

The ideal resulted table after would be like this

T1

```
Servers  DB_Names    Datafile_Size, …. 

S1       D1           2M
S1       D2           3M
S1       D3           5M
S2       D1           3M
S2       D2           6M
.
.
.
```

One way I could think of is to loop through the whole table T1 and construct a dynamic SQL in each loop to query the corresponding linked server and insert to the other fields DB_Names and Datafile_size.
But I am trying to avoid doing this because I have many linked servers rows in that column. Is there any way we could accomplish this by using set based operations?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `[DB_Names]` also populated to start with along with `[Servers]`?

Comment: yes, at the beginning the DB_NAMES AND Datafile_size are all NULL. We only have the Servers column containing all the linked servers names as data. I want to query something like S1.sys.master.databases on each row, so the result i am looking for would be like what it shows in the T1 now. Thanks

Comment: And one more thing, you're only interested in the databases represented in the list and not necessarily ALL databases on that server?

Comment: Yes i need ALL databases on each linked server. I am building up a central monitoring server to collect monitored servers' data files information for capacity planning or whatever. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all databases on the remote servers I would consider changing to a 2 table approach.  Your first table will be a table containing all of the linked servers you wish to query.  You'd then need to loop through a cursor that would formulate dynamic SQL statements in order to make the call across the linked servers.

Comment: I'll be happy to post some sample code shortly...  In a crunch right now at work, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to store the result in separate table. Then you can approach it in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE ServerDbs (LinkedServer VARCHAR(100), DbName VARCHAR(100))

DECLARE @q VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @q = 
    (SELECT 'INSERT INTO ServerDbs SELECT ''' + T.Server + ''', name FROM ' + T.Server + '.master.sys.databases'
    FROM T
    FOR XML PATH(''))

EXEC (@q)
```